# jQuery validation of a form name with square brackets

Tags: jquery, validation, dynamic

I have the following validation code for a text field but the 'field' below needs to be replaced with the name of the text field, which is created dynamically.

My problem is it has a square bracket in the name - `options[483998]`

How would I go about adding this to the code below as obviously if I do a direct replace of field with `options[483998]` it creates invalid coding.

```
jQuery("#product_addtocart_form").validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      range: [100, 2540]
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/sY82j/

```
jQuery("#product_addtocart_form").validate({
  rules: {
    "options[483998]": {
      required: true,
      range: [100, 2540]
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put it in quotes: `"options[483998]"`

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you able to pull this off?

```
jQuery("#product_addtocart_form").validate({
  rules: {
    'options[483998]': {
      required: true,
      range: [100, 2540]
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this as well, but my validation `API` code wont work with this technique.

```
"upload_images[]":
        {
            required: true, 
            accept:"jpg,png,jpeg"
        }
```

I'm working with a image upload input with multiple images, i need it to check if anything was selected before submitting the form. The other inputs work perfectly with the validation `API`.